# Character causing unwanted line finish in CHCSVParser

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have been using Dave DeLong's excellent CHCSVParser for the past year to create an array of arrays like this:

```
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:path encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding error:&error2];
```

I am just now having an issue. The csv file is generated from an Excel spreadsheet and the ellipsis - which Excel autocorrects into a single character - results in the end of the current array of arrays (I think it must be calling finishCurrentLine, but I can't figure out how to stop this).

1. How can I stop "…" from causing the array of arrays to finish?
2. What can I do to prevent other characters from causing similar problems?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried different character encodings?  Excel on a Mac might use Latin1, UTF or Mac depending on the version.

Comment: The excel file on both Mac and Windows produces the same type of CSV (windows) for which the Latin1 works the best.

Comment: Thanks @DavidH - that will surely be more accurate. I'll investigate.

Comment: Moved comment to answer, and if you end up using one or the other please accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in the ".xls" format, you can use the [libxls](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libxls/) open source library on SourceForge to read the file directly - and get the exact text or number for each cell. Also, there is an [ObjectiveC framework wrapper](http://github.com/dhoerl/DHlibxls) too.